# how to extract objects from array of object based on similar id

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have created this sample code , to explain what i am tring to do .

```js
arr = [
  { id:1 , name:'a', title: 'qmummbw' },
  { id:2 , name:'b', title: 'sdmus' },
  { id:2 , name:'', title: 'dvfv' },
  { id:3 , name:'c', title: 'dujuw' },
  { id:1 , name:'d', title: 'ccnyu' },
  { id:4 , name:'e', title: 'tjtjn' },
  { id:4 , name:'f', title: 'tryr' },
  { id:1 , name:'g', title: 'gbgfbgf' },
  { id:2 , name:'h', title: 'tgrtg' },
  { id:3 , name:'i', title: 'fdvd' },
  { id:1 , name:'j', title: 'dsnyc' },
  { id:1 , name:'k', title: 'nyuny' }
];

array = [];
allArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i].id === arr[j].id) {
      if (!array.includes(arr[i])) {
        array.push(arr[i], arr[j]);
      } else {
        array.push(arr[j]);
      }
      allArray.push(array);

      array = []
    }

  }
}
console.log(allArray);
```

Output i am getting is:

```
[[{
  id: 1,
  name: "a",
  title: "qmummbw"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "d",
  title: "ccnyu"
}], [[circular object Object], {
  id: 1,
  name: "g",
  title: "gbgfbgf"
}], [[circular object Object], {
  id: 1,
  name: "j",
  title: "dsnyc"
}], [[circular object Object], {
  id: 1,
  name: "k",
  title: "nyuny"
}], [{
  id: 2,
  name: "b",
  title: "sdmus"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "",
  title: "dvfv"
}], [[circular object Object], {
  id: 2,
  name: "h",
  title: "tgrtg"
}], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]], [{
  id: 3,
  name: "c",
  title: "dujuw"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "i",
  title: "fdvd"
}], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]], [{
  id: 4,
  name: "e",
  title: "tjtjn"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "f",
  title: "tryr"
}], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]], [[circular object Object], [circular object Object]]]
```

My main goal is to get the array of object , each object containing the same id together and keeping in mind that the  arr = [] can have n no of data.

Comment: do you need to sort the array by the ids objects?

Comment: hi , i want that the array of objects with same ids in every object , like [{
  id: 1,
  name: "a",
  title: "qmummbw"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "d",
  title: "ccnyu"
}] and [{
  id: 2,
  name: "j",
  title: "qmummbw"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "h",
  title: "ccnyu"
}]  and so on.. Is it possible

Comment: You want to create an array of arrays from the input array. Each array in this larger array, should contain only objects with the same id. Do I understand what you want to do correctly?

Comment: I suggest you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Code-Apprentice , yes

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `id` and take the values form the object, if necessary.

```js
const
    array = [{ id: 1 , name: 'a', title: 'qmummbw' }, { id: 2 , name: 'b', title: 'sdmus' }, { id: 2 , name: '', title: 'dvfv' }, { id: 3 , name: 'c', title: 'dujuw' }, { id: 1 , name: 'd', title: 'ccnyu' }, { id: 4 , name: 'e', title: 'tjtjn' }, { id: 4 , name: 'f', title: 'tryr' }, { id: 1 , name: 'g', title: 'gbgfbgf' }, { id: 2 , name: 'h', title: 'tgrtg' }, { id: 3 , name: 'i', title: 'fdvd' }, { id: 1 , name: 'j', title: 'dsnyc' }, { id: 1 , name: 'k', title: 'nyuny' }],
    grouped = array.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.id] = r[o.id] || []).push(o), r), {});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: yes , i was looking for this result as an output .. thanks Nina

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method like this:

```
const filteredArray = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (acc[el.id] || (acc[el.id] = [])) {
    acc[el.id].push(el);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
    { id:1 , name:'a', title: 'qmummbw' },
    { id:2 , name:'b', title: 'sdmus' },
    { id:2 , name:'', title: 'dvfv' },
    { id:3 , name:'c', title: 'dujuw' },
    { id:1 , name:'d', title: 'ccnyu' },
    { id:4 , name:'e', title: 'tjtjn' },
    { id:4 , name:'f', title: 'tryr' },
    { id:1 , name:'g', title: 'gbgfbgf' },
    { id:2 , name:'h', title: 'tgrtg' },
    { id:3 , name:'i', title: 'fdvd' },
    { id:1 , name:'j', title: 'dsnyc' },
    { id:1 , name:'k', title: 'nyuny' }
  ],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.id] = r[a.id] || [];
        r[a.id].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null))).map(e => e);

console.log([result]);
```